# iOS UIDocumentInteractionController, presentOptionsMenuFromRect fails, but presentOpenInMenuFromRect works

Tags: ios, swift

Whenever I try show the `UIDocumentInteractionController` with the method `presentOptionsMenuFromRect` no file is attached in the opening app and I get this in the console:
`Couldn't get file size for (null): (null)`

But if I test with `presentOpenInMenuFromRect` it works perfectly fine. I also use `presentPreviewAnimated` with its delegates and this works too. Also tested successfully switching to an UIActivityViewController. The file I try to open is a PDF stored in the local documents directory

```
let documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(URL: url)
documentInteractionController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(self.view.bounds, inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

Xcode: 7.3.1 (Swift)
iOS: 9.3 tested with simulator and device, deployment target is 8.0

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because in your code, the UIDocumentInteractionController instance might be being released by reaching the end of a function, while it's needed to let the other app handle the file properly after selecting an option from the menu.

To avoid this problem, **we need to store a strong reference to our document interaction controller in a place that will exist for the lifetime of the object's owner (i.e. a global variable)** in order to keep it alive.

Note: Apparently, this behavior does not occur with some of the options from the Open In menu nor by sharing with AirDrop.